# wordpress galleryslider hardcode

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using a plugin called Slideshow Gallery for Wordpress.

i found the hardcode so i can put in my own theme. I have different gallery's, how do i specify on a page what gallery should be showed.

This i the code that calls the gallery... but i calls every gallery i have. Is there a way that i from dashboard - pages i can specify the gallery id ?

```
 <?php if (function_exists('slideshow')) { slideshow($output = true, $gallery_id = false,   $post_id = false, $params = array()); } ?>.
```

anyone that can help ? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$gallery_id = false` needs to be the ID of the gallery that you created in the back end of wordpress.

Later in the code:

```
if($gallery_id == false){ 
    //code to show all galleries
}else{
    //code to get gallery by ID
}
```

Which is why you're seeing all the galleries.

Comment: i'm using the same template for different pages.. but i would like to have differences gallery on those pages... is that possible